# Laptop getting shutdown / run by battery after 10 minutes

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

Laptop is getting shut down after 10 minutes while it's run without battery -  but with battery as well as plugged in it runs first 10 minutes by power then automatically runs by battery until the battery runs out and the laptop is not also charging after 10 minutes.

I can charge the battery in full while the laptop is shutdown. I'

HP i7 4GB RAM Windows 7 OS about 2 years old laptop.

Comment: What model number does your laptop have? Are you able to try a different power adapter?

Comment: This sounds like the laptop is overheating.  I would clean the insides of your laptop and if possible reapply the thermal paste to the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like the laptop may be overheating.

Make sure you are running it on a hard surface and that the vents are not blocked.

As this is an HP i7, does it have the HP utility that runs the fans up to their highest speed to try to blow the dust out? Can't remember what it is called but I know that HP ship that as part of their toolset.

Also, manually inspect all of the vents to see if any are blocked.

Also make sure that you have not used a utility to restrict the fan speeds to make things quieter. An i7 is a VERY powerful CPU and will generate a lot of heat when running hard. So also ensure that you don't have something running that is driving up the CPU levels. Have a look in task manager - if the CPU is continually running over 10% without any other applications loaded, something needs to be uninstalled. My i5 laptop is running at 3-6% with several firefox windows and task manager running plus a load of background apps that are largely inactive just now.

You could also try running a Linux boot disk to see if that makes a difference - you can download them and burn onto a CD/DVD that you can then boot from. That will tell you if it is some problem in Windows. If it is, you might need to reinstall Windows or at least clear out all those old apps that tend to accumulate. If it still happens, it is very likely to be a hardware fault that will need a specialist to look at.